# declare self association many to many in mvc4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

i want to say that a drug can have one or more similar drugs, therefore its a many to many self relationship.

trying to this in this way

```
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [ForeignKey("drug_name")]
    public string drug_name1 { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [ForeignKey("drug_name")]
    public string drug_name2 { get; set; }

    public virtual Drug drug_name { get; set; }
    public virtual Drug drug_name { get; set; }
```

of course its not working. im not really understand the names should give to the related fields on the Foreign table. i need 2 of them: drug1 and drug2 but the names should be identical to those on the related class, but i can't give 2 fields the same name.so how can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

What you have is pretty much completely wrong, so let me just show you the correct way:

```
public class Drug
{
    [Key]
    public int DrugId { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual ICollection<Drug> SimilarDrugs { get; set; }

    public class DrugMapping : EntityTypeConfiguration<Drug>
    {
        public DrugMapping()
        {
            HasMany(m => m.SimilarDrugs).WithMany();
        }
    }
}
```

Then in your context:

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
    modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new Drug.DrugMapping());
}
```

For